# mod_rewrite Adds .php Extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My .htaccess file is as follows:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

The issue that I am having is that when I try to access my site without the www. prefix, the .php extension is added to the address, which can often cause a problem. For example, if I try to access my homepage with the address example.com, that address is transformed into www.example.com/.php. I want the www. to be added, but the .php extension added at the end just causes an error. How do I fix this?

Comment: This is unsafe way of rewrite "/x"->"/x.php"

Comment: RewriteRule cannot _change_ the URL in the browser address bar. You need `[R]` (redirect) flag to redirect browser to new URLs.

Comment: What is removing the php extension?

Comment: Good question from Jon Lin, how is the php being "removed" from the address bar in ~any~ case, when you do not have a RewriteRule that would do that. Your rule would only allow access to the .php file if you leave the .php off in the first place.

Comment: So how do I get it to remove the php? And why is the .php extension added automatically if I try to access my site without the www. prefix?

Comment: For example if I typed into my address bar mysite.com/main, wouldn't the first rewrite rule add the www. and the second rewrite rule would allow me to access a file called main.php? Why is the .php extension being added to the end of mysite.com/main automatically?

Comment: I completely changed my question to clarify things. Please look at it again and hopefully it will make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]`

Remove the L in the `[R=301,L]`, which means "Last", which means "stop processing RewriteRules after this one."

The 301 also means "redirect permanently." In this case, your browser will remember the permanent redirect. Is it possible that you had one version of your rewrite rules, went to your URL, and then changed it? Clear your cache or try another browser.

Comment: I tried doing that but it didn't work. The issue still exists: when I enter in mysite.com/main I am immediately transferred to www.mystie.com/main.php, but I don't want that .php extension.

Comment: Edited my answer. Note 301, the redirect may be cached in your browser.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried three different browsers and cleared the cache on all of them but still got the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The "L" flag on line 4 of your file means "last", i.e., it won't process any more rules. Try removing the L.

Comment: I tried doing that but it didn't work. The issue still exists: when I enter in mysite.com/main I am immediately transferred to www.mystie.com/main.php, but I don't want that .php extension.